# How to read response api json in laravel view

Tags: json, laravel, api, decode

h-e-l-l-o everyone

I received this response

[image]

now I want to use foreach in my View file to show all of the users

this is my Controller Functions:

```
public function ShowUserList()
{
    return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
}

public function ShowUser()
{
    $users = $this->ShowUserList();
    return view('show_users', compact('users'));        
}
```

and when I render it in view I received the response that I uploaded on top

Comment: May I ask, if you want to use it in foreach loop, why you're trying to send json data?

Answer (score 1):

at the `ShowUserList()` method, you're not just getting json data also also you're trying to send a response..

```
public function ShowUserList()
{
    return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
}
```

so you need to change it like;

```
public function ShowUserList()
{
    return User->all()->toJson();
}
```

Comment: thanks, Bro I need ShowUserList Method as API base code, so is "return User->all()->toJson();" API base?

Answer (score 1):

```
if I understood your question , try like below code ...

//in your controller class..

public function ShowUserList()
{
    return response()->json([
                           'status_code'=>200,
                           'data'=>User::all(),
                           'error' => false
                         ]);
}

// in your view file..

var response = JSON.parse(response)
if(!response.error){
    for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; ++i){
         console.log(response.data[i].name+' '+response.data[i].email)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Bro can you please edit your view code and change it to blade?

Comment: for example you code is js and I need to use it html with blade and use @foreach

Comment: how do you fetch data in your view file using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

if i'm right you need to parse json in view.

```
public function ShowUserList()
{
    return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
}

public function ShowUser()
{
    $users = json_decode( $this->ShowUserList(), true );
    return view('show_users', compact('users'));        
}
```

so based on this in your view you can do this:

```
// now this is just an json object not array..

  {{ $user['id'] }}
  {{ $user['name'] }}
```

hope i helped you..

Comment: I got error bro,Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag as array (View: /Users/lolek/Desktop/lolek/resources/views/ShowUser.blade.php)